# Angular Material few instances of "sidenav" in one component

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material does not work in manner clearly apparent! :(
**how to use a few instances of " material sidenav" ??**

(*THE MY CASE*)

### I have a few of buttons and i want that each to open another cointainer of sidenav.

---

*solution 1°*

each one individually works!, but all each together unfortunately not works!

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <nav>
        <button mat-fab (click)="menuA.toggle()">/button>
            <button mat-fab (click)="menuB.toggle()">/button>
                <button mat-fab (click)="menuC.toggle()">/button>
    </nav>
    <aside>
        <mat-sidenav #menuA align="start" mode="over" opened="false">
            <!-- sidenav content -->
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav #menuB align="start" mode="over" opened="false">
            <!-- sidenav content -->
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav #menuC align="end" mode="over" opened="false">
            <!-- sidenav content -->
        </mat-sidenav>
    </aside>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I wonder why above solution does not work!?

---

*solution 2°*

Vicariously - I try make this in another way. But this method will require that each "sidenav" has the same input parameters.

Depending which the button, had used, will have been displayed various
the contents, (I keep only one instances of sidenav, but inside I created new vicariously-skelet: such a lot of instances of child "div" of the "sidenav",
how many to need various instances of the "sidenav")

---

#### But can I do this otherwise, without adds extra of outlandish ?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: This kind of goes away from Angular - Material style guide in general which is why it's not available. The closest will be an accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hooray!

**I was able to do it!**
at this point it works correctly, partly in response to my expectations (how to make that one be open in right side and the other on the left side?)

This is my fix Solution:

---

**My.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <nav>
        <button(click)="toggleSideNavSetIn('panelA')"> A </button>
        <button(click)="toggleSideNavSetIn('panelB')"> B </button>
        <button(click)="toggleSideNavSetIn('panelC')"> C </button>
        <button(click)="toggleSideNavSetIn('panelD')"> D </button>
        <button(click)="toggleSideNavSetIn('panelE')"> E </button>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <!-- primary content -->
    </main>
    <mat-sidenav #MyInstSideNav align="start" mode="side" opened="false"  [ngSwitch]="toggleSideNavSetOut">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'panelA'">
            <mat-toolbar><h1>{{toggleSideNavSetOut}}</h1></mat-toolbar><div> <!-- sidenav content A --> </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'panelB'">
            <mat-toolbar><h1>{{toggleSideNavSetOut}}</h1></mat-toolbar><div> <!-- sidenav content B --> </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'panelC'">
            <mat-toolbar><h1>{{toggleSideNavSetOut}}</h1></mat-toolbar><div> <!-- sidenav content C --> </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'panelD'">
            <mat-toolbar><h1>{{toggleSideNavSetOut}}</h1></mat-toolbar><div> <!-- sidenav content D --> </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'panelE'">
            <mat-toolbar><h1>{{toggleSideNavSetOut}}</h1></mat-toolbar><div> <!-- sidenav content E --> </div>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

---

**My.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgStyle, NgClass, NgSwitch } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-My',
    templateUrl: './My.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./My.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    preserveWhitespaces: false,
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('MyInstSideNav') MyInstSideNav:any;
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() { }
    toggleSideNavSetOut: string ="";
    toggleSideNavSetIn(toggleSideNavGet: string){
        if (this.MyInstSideNav.opened===false) {
            this.toggleSideNavSetOut = toggleSideNavGet; 
            this.MyInstSideNav.toggle();
        } else if (this.MyInstSideNav.opened===true && this.toggleSideNavSetOut != toggleSideNavGet) {
            this.toggleSideNavSetOut = toggleSideNavGet; 
        } else {
            this.MyInstSideNav.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Can it be done in yet another way?